# T-SQL split row into multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the table in sql db like this.

```
Category Series Value
  1        A    100
  2        B    200
  2        C    300
```

How do I select to project like this?

```
Category Series Value
  1        A    100
  1        B    0
  1        C    0
  2        A    0
  2        B    200
  2        C    300
```

Comment: Uh, can you explain that?

Comment: Yes you can usually with a simple LEFT OUTER JOIN but you first need to tell us what values the row can take. In other words where does the 0 in **both** 1, A, 0 rows come from, etc.?

Comment: Yikes. True! I didn't explain well. I made some edits afterwards that will make things clear for sure. Category 1 doesn't have value B and C as from the table above but Category 2 has both values B and C but doesn't have A. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the result, you will want to generate a list of all categories with each series.  You can use a CROSS JOIN to get the result:

```
select distinct c.category, s.series
from yourtable s
cross join yourtable c
```

Once you have this, then you can join this back to your table on both the `category` and `series`:

```
select sc.category,
  sc.series,
  coalesce(t.value, 0) value
from 
(
  select distinct c.category, s.series
  from yourtable s
  cross join yourtable c
) sc
left join yourtable t
  on sc.series = t.series
  and sc.category = t.category;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e9bf/2)